# How do I have an element follow the mouse without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have this but it doesn't work

```
var box = document.getElementById("box");

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    var left = e.pageX;
    box.style.left = left;
});
```

If I just replace **box.style.left = left;** with jQuery it works fine

```
$('#wrap').css ({   
    left: left  
});
```

but I'm just so confused... Why is **box.style.left = left;** not working when it's practically the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS `left` property requires units. You're not giving it any. jQuery's [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) adds `"px"` for you when you give it a number, which is why the jQuery one works.

Add a `"px"`:

```
box.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
```

Comment: Thanks!! It's always dumb mistakes like this that keeps me scratching my head for hours haha

Answer (score 3):

You also have to give top value

Hope this snippet will help

```js
    var box = document.getElementById("box");

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    var left = e.pageX+"px";
    box.style.left = left;
});
```

```css
.moveAble {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="moveAble">
AAAA
</div>
```

Comment: *"You also have to give top value"* The OP said just setting `left` with jQuery worked, so we know that's not the case for their question. (Of course, yes, you'd have to set `top` if you want it to follow vertically as well as horizontally, but the key here is why doing it with the DOM didn't work but doing it with jQuery did.)

Comment: Yes you are right. I missed the without Jquery Part. I have updated the snippet